# Compiler generates FPU instructions

Tags: stm32, cmsis

I realize a CMSIS Project solution with VS Code but I've an error on an include file :

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
```

And I've got this error :

```
In included file: "Compiler generates FPU instructions for a device without an FPU (check __FPU_PRESENT)"clang(pp_hash_error)
core_cm3.h(90, 6): Error occurred here
```

The path of this file is here :

```
C:\Users\"name"\AppData\Local\Arm\Packs\Keil\STM32F1xx_DFP\2.4.0\Device\Include
```

But I think I forgot something during the configuration.

I justa want to build my C file but VS code doesn't make the link between my .h and my CMSIS project.

Answer (score 1):

You are never supposed to `#include "stm32f10x.h"`

You only `#include "stm32f1xx.h"` and it will include the other headers you need.

You must also define a macro on the command line, one of `STM32F101x6`, `STM32F101xB`, `STM32F101xE` or `STM32F101xG`.

For most compilers you can define this with an argument like `-DSTM32F101xB`.

After that you will need particular command line arguments that match your chosen processor, such as `-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mfpu=none`.

Maybe your error was specifying an incorrect `-mfpu=`.

Comment: I try to use `#include "stm32f1xx.h"` but now I've another problem in my C file.
I've this error : `Include file not found in browse.path. C/C++`

Comment: If you read the message what do you think you might do to fix it?

Comment: I think I have to add the path of the stm32f1xx.h in the parameters of vscode.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea!